# Tell NPM to install in different directory

Tags: npm

I have a situation where due to the requirements/opinion of a project I'm working with, I have to keep my `package.json` file in a nested directory. See below:

```
/my-app
  |-- /functions
    |-- /node_modules
    |-- package.json
```

The problem I have run into several times now is that I run `npm i <package>` from within `/my-app` and not `/my-app/functions` without realizing it and I end up spending time unnecessary time debugging my app because I installed the package in the wrong place.

Is there a way to create a root-level `package.json` file that merely tells NPM, "hey, if you're going to install something, do it in this other directory."? For example:

```
/my-app
  |-- package.json <-- add this
  |-- /functions
    |-- /node_modules
    |-- package.json
```

And maybe the `package.json` file within the root directory would look something like this?

```
{
  "installDirectory": "/functions"
}
```

This functionality may already exist, but I was unable to find it in the documentation. The `--prefix` flag is similar, but it doesn't automatically handle the case I'm describing.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the right tool but I would take a look at [Yarn Workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2017/08/02/introducing-workspaces/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use npm-config:

```
$ npm config set prefix ./functions
```

Or you could set `NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX` (environment variable) to `./functions`.

You could also add this line to `.npmrc`:

```
prefix = ./functions
```

The npm docs:

- [How to set a config key](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config.html#set)
- [How `prefix` is used](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#node-modules)
- [npmrc documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc)

Comment: I just added `prefix = ./functions` to `.npmrc`, but when I run `npm i --save <package>`, it still installs at the root and not at /functions. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried the other methods? Also, why `--save`? Packages are added as dependencies by default in npm 5 and above; which version are you using?

Comment: Try `$ npm prefix` and see its output as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not setting the path in package.json, but with the npm [prefix](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prefix.html) flag you can set the instalation path of node_modules when installing packages.

eg: `$ npm install <package> --prefix ./functions/node_modules`

Comment: Yeah, I know the prefix flag will work, but my goal is to get it to automatically know the correct directory without specifying inline, as I always forget to do.